# Endless function calling loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on my iOS project again. However, I seem to have hit a cascading eternal loop of function calls of which I don't know why it happens. The GDB output can be viewed here:

http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/527/gdberror.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dot notation is a syntactic sugar for setter/getter methods.

```
self.username = x;
```

is the same as

```
[self setUsername:x];
```

Answer (score 3):

`self.username` uses the `setUsername` method, hence your issue. Just use:

```
username = user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.self` from your code.

When you write `self.username` you are calling your `-(void)setuserName:(NSString*)user` function again and again.

it should be

```
-(void)setUserName:(NSString*)user{
      userName = user;
}
```